# After switch to mongoDB auth::attempt is not working laravel 9

Tags: php, mysql, mongodb, jwt, laravel-9

Here is my code which is working fine with MySQL but when I switch MySQL to MongoDB registration is working properly but the login attempt is returning false.

I am creating an API for login and registration for my project.

I have also implemented JWT token package in laravel 9.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use App\Models\User;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
 public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth:api', ['except' => ['login','register']]);
}

public function login(Request $request)
{
$request->validate([
'strEmail' => 'required|string|email',
'strPassword' => 'required|string',
]);
$credentials = $request->only('strEmail', 'strPassword');
    
$token = Auth::attempt($credentials);
if (!$token) {
return response()->json([
'status' => 'error',
'message' => 'Unauthorized',
], 401);
}

$user = Auth::user();

return response()->json([
'status' => 'success',
'user' => $user,
'authorisation' => [
'token' => $token,
'type' => 'bearer',
]
]);

}

public function register(Request $request){
$request->validate([
'strFirstName' => 'required|string|max:255',
'strLastName' => 'required|string|max:255',
'strEmail' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
'strPassword' => 'required|string|min:6',   
]);

$user = User::create([
'strFirstName' => $request->strFirstName,
'strLastName' => $request->strLastName,
'strEmail' => $request->strEmail,
'strPassword' => Hash::make($request->strPassword),
'isLogin' => 1,
'LastLoginDate'=> Carbon::now(),
'EnterDatetime' => new \DateTime(),
'IP' => \Request::ip(),
]);

$token = Auth::login($user);
return response()->json([
'status' => 'success',
'message' => 'User created successfully',
'user' => $user,
'authorisation' => [
'token' => $token,
'type' => 'bearer',
]
]);
}
}
```

here is the user model

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use PHPOpenSourceSaver\JWTAuth\Contracts\JWTSubject;
use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Authenticatable implements JWTSubject
{
use HasFactory, Notifiable;

/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array<int, string>
 */
```

please help.

I have tried this code with MySQL and both registration and login work with MySQL.

Comment: Try: `\DB::enableQueryLog(); $token = Auth::attempt($credentials); dd(\DB::getQueryLog());` Check what does it output.

Comment: it shows array:1 [ // app\Http\Controllers\Api\AuthController.php:28
  0 => array:3 [
    "query" => "users.find({"$and":[{"strEmail":"myemail"},{"strPassword":"password"}]},{"limit":1,"typeMap":{"root":"array","document":"array"}})"
    "bindings" => []
    "time" => 1.23
  ]
]

Comment: See the query being executed. Try running the same command via mongosh

Comment: the query is not returning anything because the password is not encrypted.

Comment: So while putting the password, encrypt it using : `Hash::make('password')`; Also you could

Comment: I can not do that because every time hash is creating the different string.I am not that much aware of how auth: attempt works.but the same code is working in MySQL so there may be some functionality that it identified encrypted passwords.

Comment: No, the hash::make('password') would return the same hash. This is how `Hash::check` works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it. Auth only accepts the password field as a "password".